# HTML5 "A numeric character reference expanded to the C1 controls range" error when using &#147;

Tags: html

i have this html code:

```
<span class="comma_left">&#147;</span>
```

And

```
<span class="comma_right">&#148;</span>
```

As well, both representing left & right commas.

Strange thing though, [HTML5 validation](http://validator.w3.org/) throws the error:

> *"A numeric character reference expanded to the C1 controls range."*

I really don't want to just avoid this error, what can i do?

Comment: Are you sure about the codes? 147 (U+0093) and 148 (U+0094) are not valid Unicode code points.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [C1 control range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) refers to characters mapped to byte encodings 0x80 to 0x9f (128 to 159) in [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), or to [Unicode code points U+0080 to U+009F](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).  Unicode considers these to be ["control characters"](https://unicode.org/glossary/#control_codes), which are explicitly [disallowed by the HTML5 parsing algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#character-references).

Your problem is occurring because you're using the [Windows code page 1252](https://web.archive.org/web/20160328002932/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305145.aspx) encodings of directed double-quote marks, which are incompatible with both Latin-1 and Unicode.  You could try these compatible variants:

- Left double-quote: [`&ldquo;` or `&#8220;`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm)
- Right double-quote: [`&rdquo;` or `&#8221;`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm)

Comment: The full conversion list is at http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html#compare -- match the **1252(dec)** column with the **NCR** column

Answer (score 3):

Try to change `&#147;` by `&#8220;` and `&#148;` by `&#8221;` it seen to be the same caracter and valid W3C.