# Error 403 when posting on Facebook a Joomla URL for multilingual site

Tags: facebook, joomla, joomla3.0, http-status-code-403

I have a multilingual Joomla3 website

www.mekako.fr

the server redirects to french language by default (or Italian/English it detects those lagnuages)

The problem arises when I try to posto to a Facebook wall/page a link to www.mekako.fr, it gives a "403 access denied", if I post www.mekako.fr/fr or www.mekako.fr/it it is ok...
We are on Windows Hosting, no .htaccess, but web.config is used...

Any explanation? is the "root url" unavailable because it redirects to the correct language?

Comment: The FB scraper is perfectly capable of following correctly implemented redirects. But there seem to be other issues with your page, the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) complains about character encoding problems. The [HTML validator also notes these](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mekako.fr%2F), saying _“A numeric character reference expanded to the C1 controls range”_. As for what that means, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5379963/1427878

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, following the links you provided I found a hint about GZIP compression...
Disabled GZIP compression in Joomla and everything is working perfectly now...

see: 
[Facebook Open Graph, required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405457/facebook-open-graph-required-property-ogtitle-of-type-string-was-not-provi)